# How do i add new android screen for UI testing in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, screen

Currently i have the following screen definition listed by Eclipse. I would like to add at least 2 more screens so that i don't have to run it on the actual device for every time i make a small changes to the layout.

[image: Current screen definition]

I would like to add the following two screens:

480 x 800 pixels, 4.3 inches (~217 ppi pixel density)
1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density)

Could anyone tell me how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]    select Preview All Screens so you can show many layouts in screen

Comment: I did that already. What i did not know is that i have to restart Eclipse (close and start it again) so that it is displayed there. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can create new virtual device from android virtual device manager -> device definitions -> new device..